# Upgraded MVC3 projetcs to MVC5 open in VS.Net 2015 Admin Only

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I have upgraded few of our ASP.Net MVC3 applications to ASP.Net MVC5. The migration was done on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise in Admin mode.
All went successful, projects built successfully, but when same projects open in Visual Studio 2015 without Admin mode, IDE is not able to open them.
Below is the error,

```
D:\Source\ProjA\XYZ.Web.csproj : error  : Access to the path 'D:\Source\ProjA\XYZ.Web.csproj' is denied.

 : error  : The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.
```

I did check folder and files has sufficient privilege to read/write. 
Do anyone know what could be the reason?

Comment: Make sure the current Windows user has access to those files?

Comment: Full permission provided I checked, still issue is same.

Comment: Please consider trying to raise the visibility of this problem with Microsoft. See https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9561930-improve-the-the-parameter-is-incorrect-feature

Answer (score 0):

```
    <FileUpgradeFlags></FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation></UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion></OldToolsVersion>
```

Above were added after migration, made them  blank and resolved the issue.